# css - max-height: 100% doesn't work on textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have a `div`, which consists of a header, textarea and a footer. The header and footer are as big as their content and the textarea takes up the remaining space. The textarea has a `max-height` of 100% , because the height of the textarea should not be more than 100%. However, if you resize the textarea, the textarea gets higher than 100% of the parent. How to prevent this?

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/FC7eY/1650/

Summary:

- The sum of the heights of all the elements must be 100%
- The height of the `textarea-wrapper` div should be `totalHeight(100%) - headerHeight - footerHeight`
- The header and footer must not have a fixed height, they should be as big as their content.
- The height of the parent/wrapper div must be 80% and the width must be 350px

Comment: Since you have height 100% for every parent, your content will grow dynamically based on the height of the children; in this case, the textarea. It's doing what you have told it to do :)

Comment: Can you explain little more clearly of how exactly you want the output

Comment: @Geeky Of course, I added a summary to my question. I hope it's all clear now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see those at same screen size you can use calc css for textarea's height and width. and you use display table and table-row for see all element in any screen size, well you can use height calc function in teaxarea div for the height and remove the header and footer height from that something like 
** Check the update [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/as58601r/1/) see the css part

**UPDATE: Now 2nd div  will take the remaining height and width and text area will not overflow horizontally**

```css
html,
body,
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
  width: 350px;
  height: 80%;
  display: table;
  border: 3px solid magenta;
}

.wrap > div {
  background: red;
  display: table-row;
    height: 0;
}

#textarea-wrapper {
  background: pink;
  height: auto;
}

#text {
  max-width: calc(350px - 3px);
  max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <div id="header">Header<br>Header<br>Header<br>Header<br>Header<br></div>
 <div id="textarea-wrapper">
   <textarea id="text"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">Footer<br>Footer<br>Footer<br>Footer<br></div>
</div>
```

Comment: My header and footer don't have a fixed height. They should be as high as their content.

Comment: Then try  max and min width heigth 100% in textarea#text {max-height: 100% ;  max-width: 100%;}

Comment: @UUioP see the update . Maybe it will help you out. :)

Comment: @Thanks! Will this work if you wrap it in another div?

Comment: @UUioP then the class or id of the div will replace with body section [ http://jsfiddle.net/as58601r/2/ ]

Comment: I want the height of my div to be 80% and the width 350px. Sorry for not mentioning it in my question, didn't know it was necessary.

Comment: @UUioP replace the value in my last fiddle the wrap  div height to  80% and the width 350px . Also replace max-width and max-height of the textarea id #text like max-width: calc(350px - 3px); max-height: 100%; . I think it will be ok